# Textbook on the Theory of Orthogonal Matrices

Tags: matrices, reference-request

Is there a textbook with good coverage on the theory of orthogonal matrices?  If possible, I would prefer that the orthogonal matrices are allowed to have complex entries.

Note that I am not interested in matrix analysis, which seems to be quite a popular subject within matrix theory (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374523/matrix-theory-textbook-recommendation) for example).

Comment: Michael Artin's "Algebra"?

Comment: Maybe you'll be interested in the special groups.

Comment: @AlgebraAnalysisManifolds It is not specific (if it were, I would just ask about that instead).  My interests lie in combinations, which may help to explain why I have explicitly excluded analysis.

Comment: @metacompactness Sure, discussion about the special orthogonal matrices would also be welcomed but is not necessary.

Comment: Note that the complex-entry analog to the orthogonal matrix is the *unitary* matrix.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sometimes, but not in my case.  I truly am interested complex matrices $M$ such that $M M^{T} = I$.

Comment: A few books that might help you are mentioned in the answers at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28980/simplicity-of-complex-orthogonal-groups